# Почему выдаёт непонятное число

Tags: delphi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
      Edit1: TEdit;
      Button1: TButton;
      Button2: TButton;
      Button3: TButton;
      procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
      procedure Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);    
    private
      FFine1,  FFine2, FzDva : real;
      { Private declarations }
    public
      { Public declarations }
  end;

var
Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}



procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FzDva := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  Edit1.Text := FloatToStr(FFine2);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    fFine1 := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
    Edit1.Clear;

    if (Sender as Tbutton).Name = 'Button1' then begin
        FFine2 := fFine1 + FzDva;
    end
    else begin
        if (Sender as Tbutton).Name = 'Button3' then begin
            FFine2 := FFine1 - FzDva;
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
    // разрешить ввод цифр, запятой, знака '-' и backspace
    if not (key in ['0'.. '9', #8, #44]) then
        // в противном случае не вводить ничего
        key:= #0;
end;

end.
```

Почему выдаёт непонятное число ? Начало такое происходить после добавления слушателя событий других кнопок.

Как работает:

1 Вписываем значение в эдит

2 Нажимаем на плюс (минус)

3 Вписываем новое значение

4 Нажемаем равно

5 Должно получиться валидное значение (в этом пункте проблема)

Comment: Где выдает? Какие числа понятные, какие нет?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka на форме (один єдит три батона)

Comment: Скрин можете прикрепить? И в результате чего такое получилось.

Comment: @Metod Не понятна суть проблемы. Что вы вводите, что ожидаете и что выводится на самом деле?

Comment: @zed если слаживать (вычитать) числа то совсем левое число вылетает

Comment: дак вы в каком порядке что пишите и вводите и на кнопки жмете.

Comment: и вообще вы слышали когда нибудь про отладчик? расставьте точки останова на методах, да смотрите по шагам что у вас происходит. в чем сложность  не понятно

Comment: @teran Я только что добавил в каком порядке жать на кнопки

Comment: ну и получаться должно после этого алгоритма первое введенное, не?

Comment: "Вписываем значение в эдит" - какое? "Вписываем новое значение" - какое? "Должно получиться валидное значение" - какое?

Comment: @teran  НЕ .....

Comment: @Igor  2 + 2 = 4

Comment: @Metod а получается какое? Вы - партизан?

Comment: @Igor получается 2

Comment: ну дак я ведь написал, что получается первое :)

Comment: @teran как это изменить ?

Comment: Ваш же код! Вы можете проследить выполнение кода - строчку за строчкой для описанной последовательности шагов? Изначально все числа равны нулю.

Comment: у вас фактическое сложение/вычитание происходит при нажатии кнопки `+/-`, а должно быть при нажатии `=`. Когда жмете плюс, у вас второго аргумента еще нет, а вы уже складывать пытаетесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я всё правильно понял, событие `Button1Click` это нажатие кнопки `+` или `-`. И в этом событии вы считываете значение первого операнда в `FFine1` и тут же, не дождавшись ввода второго операнда, начинаете выполнять расчёты и обращаетесь к переменной `FzDva`, в которую вы ещё не занесли никакого значения. В итоге у вас и получается не то, что нужно.

Вам надо переделать код так, чтобы в событии `Button1Click` вы запоминали первый операнд (в `FFine1`) и **тип операции** (сложение/вычитание/и т.д.), но саму операцию не выполнять до того момента, пока не будет нажата кнопка `=` и вы не попадёте в событие `Button2Click`. В событии же `Button2Click` вы уже можете считать значение второго операнда в `FzDva` и используя сохранённое значение первого операнда из `FFine1` и тип операции, выполнить расчёт и вывести результат.

Comment: с тем что переменная не инициализирована то вы погорячились, она член класса, так то равна нулю.

Comment: @teran Строго говоря - да, но она не инициализирована значением, которое ожидает в ней увидеть топикстартер. То, что она инициализирована значением по умолчанию (нулём), особой роли не играет.

Comment: как по мне, тут надо использовать другое слово, а не _инициализацию_, да и "мусор" там вполне поддающийся объяснению, а не абы какой. В общем, вопрос терминологии, не более.

Comment: @teran Ок, поправил терминологию.